# Communicating PLC to Android Via RsLinx?

Tags: android, plc

I am newbie to this forum, I have allen Bradley/Rockwell make PLCs which are communicating to SCADA systems in WiFi. I want to develop a android application which can read some of the PLC data.

The Rockwell PLC has RSlinix software which is a inbuilt OPC software.

I am able to read PLC tags in Excel via OPC connector.

If someone can help with Sample source code or sample codes please

Answer (score 0):

See this Python project. It works on Android

https://github.com/dmroeder/pylogix